# Solaris 11 change current image / "entire" package

Tags: solaris, repository, oracle

I need to install a new Solaris image on our server as it used to be under a support agreement but is not anymore, and as such I'm unable to download any new packages from the (https://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/support/) repository and need to download them from the (http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/) repository. However I'm getting a lot of errors and unable to install any new packages from the release repository (as I believe my "entire" image can only handle Support repo packages). Please find below the output from "pkg info entire".

```
pkg info entire
             Name: entire
          Summary: entire incorporation including Support Repository Update (Oracle Solaris 11.3.17.5.0).
      Description: This package constrains system package versions to the same
                   build.  WARNING: Proper system update and correct package
                   selection depend on the presence of this incorporation.
                   Removing this package will result in an unsupported system.
                   For more information see:
                   https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=2045311.1
         Category: Meta Packages/Incorporations
            State: Installed
        Publisher: solaris
          Version: 0.5.11 (Oracle Solaris 11.3.17.5.0)
    Build Release: 5.11
           Branch: 0.175.3.17.0.5.0    Packaging Date: February 17, 2017 02:04:57 AM Last Install Time: March 12, 2017 07:33:24 AM
             Size: 5.46 kB
             FMRI: pkg://solaris/entire@0.5.11,5.11-0.175.3.17.0.5.0:20170217T020457Z
```

I'm quite new to the Solaris environment and have searched for hours online about how to change the system image/"entire" package, however can't find anything useful. I just need to install any version of Solaris 11. Do I need to (somehow) physically access the server and re-image using a USB, or is there an easier way to just tell the system to revert to the opensource "release" version of Solaris?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `pkg set-publisher` to change the solaris repo to use the free public repository (which does not get security fixes or bug fixes between releases, just updates every couple years when a new release comes out) at `http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/` and then use `pkg update` to update to the Solaris 11.4 release there.  After you're running Solaris 11.4, then you should be able to add additional packages from that release.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, but I tried that previously (and just now) and I can change the publisher to the release repo, but when I do "pkg update" I get hundreds of "reject" errors, stating that no version matching 'require' dependency system/library can be installed
**** E.g.
 - Reject:  pkg://solaris/shell/bash@4.4.19.19-11.4.0.0.1.14.0
 - Reason:  No version matching 'require' dependency 
          system/library@11.4,5.11-11.4.0.0.1.12.2 can be installed
****